# Should the query contains partition key if we have set partition key into FeedOption already?

Tags: performance, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Document DB with partition key = "deviceId".
Is there any different between 2 code below:

```
var fo = new FeedOption{ PartitionKey= new PartitionKey("A1234") };
var partitionKeyInQuery= dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery(d => d.deviceId = "A1234" and d.type==1, fo);
var noPartitionKeyInQuery = dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery(d => d.type==1, fo);
```

When PartitionKey is applied in FeedOption, should I add "deviceId" in WHERE clause?

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no difference in performance. RequestCharge is the same and the where clause makes the query partition specific i.e eliminates cross partition query.

From the documentation:

**Querying partitioned containers**

When you query data in partitioned containers, Cosmos DB automatically routes the query to the partitions corresponding **to the partition key values specified in the filter (if there are any)**. For example, this query is routed to just the partition containing the partition key "XMS-0001".

```
// Query using partition key
IQueryable<DeviceReading> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<DeviceReading>(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("db", "coll"))
    .Where(m => m.MetricType == "Temperature" && m.DeviceId == "XMS-0001");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-partition-data

Comment: However it looks like he is also asking about querying difference (ie will the results differ)

Comment: Thank you very much for information. I want to know the RUs and performance between 2 code. The result is same.